# Create a site using powershell for a custom site definition

Tags: powershell, site-definition

I have created a custom site definition which I can see and create a site using my custom definition with the UI.  However, if I try to create a site using powershell I get an error saying `WARNING: Template is not found and is not applied.`

I have verified that the Template param for `New-SPWeb` matches the definition name and configuration Id `TestDefinition#0`.

I looked at the available web templates using the command `Get-SPWebTemplate` and my new site definition is not showing up is not available in the collection. I do see other definitions created previously but not my new one.

Anyone have any ideas why I can't create a site this way?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky, I must say.
If you use `Get-SPWebTemplate`, I think you only get the built-in templates.  If you want to find a custom site-template, you have to dance a little...

Here is what I have used, supplying the GUID along with `name` of the custom Site Template. Notice my `$sitetemplatename` - that last hash is part of the name; it isn't a comment.  You put the GUID + # + name all together, just like that.

```
#You need to fish this out of SCA.  After you have saved the site template (with content), use the ps command in BGM's profile: listwebtemplates
$sitetemplateName = "{4755D494-88F9-4F59-909E-875F6D518A56}#MySiteTemplateName"

New-SPWeb -Url $SiteUrl -Name $SiteTitle -UniquePermissions:$true -Description $sitedescription
$currentWeb = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl
write-host "Applying custom template..."
$currentWeb.ApplyWebTemplate($sitetemplateName)
$currentweb.update()
```

Comment: I think Mark asks for custom site definitions not web templates. Both should show in Get-SPWebTemplates provided the feature containing the templates are enabled. Check that the farm/site scoped feature with the site definition/web template are enabled

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Mr. Rask.  I'd hate to confuse anyone besides myself!

Comment: I'm interested to know if this was resolved.  I have the same problem.  @Anders Rask ... why would the feature be important?  Aren't Site Definitions deployed as part of the package ... not a feature?